# Where/How do You Add Documentation for Kotlin Packages?

Tags: documentation, package, kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

In Java, if you want to document a package, it has to be put into the *package-info.class* file. Is that still the same thing with Kotlin and KDoc?

I've looked through some of the Kotlin source and can't find where their package documentation is written.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html appears to be generated from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7105c7c182cc842bf4d970f9f3860aaefc2853ad/libraries/stdlib/src/Module.md which contains markup for the module and packages documentation.

Comment: I just voted to re-open this question. It is closed with motivation "question seeks recommendations for tools, etc", but that is not at all what the question is about. The question is about how to document source code properly in Kotlin.

Answer (score 7):

You use the `include` Dokka configuration option.

See: https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/master/README.md

Example: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/58e93d5e1bb547c8a7e398587b6851ccf6372326/libraries/build-docs.xml

Comment: As lousy as package-info is, I like it better than having to manually tell the generator to include certain files.

Comment: Kotlin can't use the package-info approach because the package structure in Kotlin doesn't need to match the directory structure. And with Dokka you can have one file with the descriptions of all of your packages, and not one file per package as in Java.

Comment: @yole "One file per package as in Java" is sometimes a more desirable approach. In Java/Javadoc, you have more freedom, as you can create either an `overview.html` page (one for all your packages), or separate `package-info.java` (per package), or both.