# How do I document a Kotlin package like with the Java `package-info.java` in an IntelliJ IDEA/Gradle project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kdoc

kotlinlang.org says that a [separate markdown file](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#module-and-package-documentation) documents all packages. Is there a canonical path for that markdown file in an IntelliJ IDEA project? Is there a canonical way to process that file with Gradle? Is there a way to have these .md files alongside .kt files in the package directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where/How do You Add Documentation for Kotlin Packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212451/where-how-do-you-add-documentation-for-kotlin-packages)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce your documentations using [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka), you can create a single markdown (`.md`) file with headers for each package (or probably separate markdown file in each package with a single header in that file for that package):

my-packages-docs.md:

```
# Package com.example.mylibrary.firstpackage

This is the docs for firstpackage.

# Package com.example.mylibrary.anotherpackage

This is the docs for anotherpackage.

## This is a subheader for anotherpackages docs
```

Include the markdown file in the Dokka result docs by passing the path of the file(s) to Dokka using the `-include` command line parameter or the corresponding parameters in Ant, Maven and [Gradle plugin](https://kotlin.github.io/dokka/1.6.21/user_guide/gradle/usage/#configuration-options)s.

Here is an example configuration for Dokka in my library *build.gradle.kts* file ([Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)):

```kotlin
tasks.dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        configureEach { // OR named("main") {
            includes.from("my-packages-docs.md", "another.md")
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to [Kotlin documentations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#module-and-package-documentation) for more information.